# Can we make a relation between two Generic Lists?

Tags: c#-4.0

Can we eatablish any relation between two lists?I just want to query the list and find the related result from other list.Please suggest some idea

```
class GeneralClass
    {
        //public List<int> Student_RollNumber = new List<int>();
        //public List<string> Student_Name = new List<string>();
        private List<int> _student_rollnumber = new List<int>();
        private List<string> _student_name = new List<string>();
        public List<int> Student_RollNumber
        {
            get { return _student_rollnumber; }
            set { _student_rollnumber = value; }
        }
        public List<string> Student_Name
        {
            get { return _student_name; }
            set { _student_name = value; }
        }
    }
```

```
private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                obj.Student_RollNumber.Add(int.Parse(txtbx_rollnum.Text));
                obj.Student_Name.Add(txtbx_SName.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Data saved");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message from form");
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               var result = obj.Student_Name.Contains(txtbx_find.Text).ToString();
              MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Here i want the Student name when i search for Rollnumber.Can we have multiple column's in a List.

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating a new custom class and use it as the Generic Parameter?

```
class Student
{
  public Student(int rollNumber, string name)
  {
    Name = name;
    RollNumber = rollNumber;
  }

  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public int RollNumber { get; private set; }
}

class GeneralClass
{
  private List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
  public List<Student> Students
  {
    get { return students; }
  }
}

private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    int rollNumber = int.Parse(txtbx_rollnum.Text);
    string name = txtbx_SName.Text;
    obj.Add(new Student(rollNumber, name));
    MessageBox.Show("Data saved");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message from form");
   }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you go over your questions and mark those that answered as answered.

Comment: Hi Can u explain me why you have written

Comment: <pre> public string Name { get; private set; }
  public int RollNumber { get; private set; }
                       </pre>

Comment: for setting y u have taken private.